# What to consider when choosing a crystal

Tags: avr, uart, atmega, crystal, datalogger

I'm working on a Datalogger project power by a battery that needs to take sensor measurements and broadcast the parameters to a server.
The power source to the CPU is 3.3Vcc from the battery.

The communication baud rate with sensors and the cellular modem is 19200 9600 and 1200 (SDI12),
my dilemma is in choosing the crystal for the [ATmega1280 (datasheet link)](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561-Datasheet-DS40002211A.pdf).
I'm debating between 8MHz and 4MHz.
[image: Freq vs Vcc]

I'm also using the Brown-out to protect the EEPROM and Flash from low battery conditions
The 110 line is for 4MHz and the 101 line is for 8MHz.
[image: BODLEVEL Fuse Codeing]

I'm using CodeWizardAVR for the UART configurations and these are the result for both crystals:
**8MHz:**
[image: 8MHz 1200], [image: 8MHz 9600], [image: 8MHz 19200]

**4MHz:**
[image: 4MHz 1200], [image: 4MHz 9600], [image: 4MHz 19200]

The system has **no** real-time requirement.
What should be my considerations in choosing the right crystal?
I understand that in crystal 4 the BOD level is lower so I can use the battery for longer.
But are there any other things I need to consider?

Comment: It's not "4Mhz" or "8Mhz" but "4 MHz" or "8 MHz". However, it's not as bad as saying "mhz" when you mean mega hertz. Go with the 4 MHz and design your code so that it can easily be upgraded should you fit an 8 MHz xtal.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer the 8 MHz over the 4 MHz?
battery consumption is very important to me

Comment: These devices consume less power at lower frequencies at the expense of slower processing.  As always, battery operation involves tradeoffs.  Have you looked at the AVR's sleep modes?

Comment: I'm using the sleep modes

Comment: In my experience, the internal RC oscillator (which can be calibrated relatively precisely in this case) will probably use far less current than an external crystal oscillator. Asynchronous serial bit streams are pretty robust against quite a large timing error so this may be a better choice.

Comment: @PeterSmith but it depends how you calibrate it, as the frequency will depend on both temperature and supply voltage. Even though UART comms are rather robust, in a product where it must simply work without any hassle a crystal should be used.

Comment: @PeterSmith "this may be a better choice" do you mean 4 MHz?
I don't think I can calibrate the internal oscillator to 4MHz
The calibrated RC oscillator is from 7.3-8.1 see p.45 on datasheet

Comment: @DanielSurizon you can _divide_ the internal oscillator with `CLKPR` though, and still save almost all of the power you would have at the slower frequency, since only a tiny fraction of the chip would run at the oscillator frequency.  In terms of internal vs. crystal, keep in mind that decades of work have gone into making internal oscillators good enough for this usage.  Unless you're desperately short on space though you can place the external option and experiment with or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save power and work at the lowest possible supply voltage, use a slowest possible frequency.

Since most important stuff you are doing is UART comms, select a crystal that suits best for the job, like 3.6864 MHz, which happens to provide the exact frequencies within the crystal tolerance.

Comment: In a task that's probably going to spend a fair amount of awake time waiting for serial responses, yes, a slow clock is probably useful.  Though in a more compute-centric task getting the work done quickly and going right back to sleep could be preferable.

Comment: Well any multiple of 19200*16 should do. Or 19200*8 if U2X is used. 7.3728 MHz is most likely choise as well. I forgot to mention that unfortunately, crystals take very long to wake up if stopped, and typically AVRs cannot dynamically select their clock source. The internal oscillators wake up almost instantly.