# Transmitting from PC via USART to MCU working but very slow

Tags: avr, uart

I am sending a small 16-Bit RGB BMP image file from my Linux PC via USART (with a loosely wired USB to serial converter) to an AVR ATmega MCU sitting on a breadboard, running at 8 MHz with the internal oscillator. It is working, but only very slow.

In the controller in the main loop, I am checking if data was received:

```
if (bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0)) {
    char data = UDR0;
    handle(data);
}
```

For now in `handle(data)`, I'm just counting the bytes received to be as inexpensive as possible but still being able to know if at least the correct number of bytes was received.
The main loop does nothing else.

USART is set to `BAUD = 38400` and initialized like this:

```
void initUSART(void) {
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}
```

So I set GTKTerm to 38400-8-N-1 and send the .bmp as raw file. This fails however, only about 50 of the total 650 bytes are sent and then it just stops.

The exact same happens if I just `cat small.bmp > /dev/ttyUSB0`

So I have come up with this super clumsy way of slowly sending byte by byte from the console:

```
count=0; while([ $count -lt 650 ]); do byte=$(xxd -p -l1 -s $count small.bmp); echo -en "\x$byte" > /dev/ttyUSB0; sleep 0.05; ((count=$count+1)); done
```

This works, but is obviously extremely slow, and if I reduce the `sleep` to below 0.05 seconds, transfer is unreliable.

Some info about the PC's USB:

```
Bus 002 Device 107: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 002 Device 095: ID 03eb:2104 Atmel Corp. AVR ISP mkII
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What am I missing?

Update: It seems that printing some debugging info back to the PC **while** sending data to the controller can also break communication.

Comment: The problem is likely not in the code you present, but in the one you hide (like that `handle` function). Sounds like you have an issue with timing. Maybe your handling is too slow for example. Or you have some frequent interrupt choking the main loop. Or something else

Comment: You are missing info about your PC serial port. It clearly is an USB serial port so already a red flag. What does dmesg or lsusb say about it? Do you know the chipset? Also, if you use inaccurate clocks on AVR it can't receive correctly. Are you having internal RC oscillator or external crystal, and what is the clock speed?

Comment: *only about 50 of the total 650 bytes are sent and then it just stops* - have you checked if these 50 bytes are the actual 50 bytes of the source data? I would imagine that you are missing every few bytes instead based on what you are describing..

Comment: Added infos to question. The `handle` function really just increments an integer. I also tried to echo back the bytes received via USART. Main loop does nothing else.
Clock speed is 8 MHz with the internal oscillator. Info about USB added.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right, it is not the first ~50 bytes but there are many missing in between. Interesting enough is that what is being received/echoed is repeatedly the same.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to how sending the bytes individually with a relatively long delay in between could fix the issue with the timing of the internal oscillator being off... I suppose in theory, with bad enough timing, the receiver could still be sampling the end of the previous byte when the sender started with the next one, so that an extra stop bit could help. But you'd still likely have issues with getting the last data bit right anyway, and 0.05 seconds is 1920 bit times at 38400 b/s, far larger scale than a single byte.

Comment: @ilkkachu The clock error isn't large enough to slip or gain a bit in a single character. So leaving a gap between characters allows the timing to reset between each character. Sending characters continuously with no gap between a stop bit and the following start bit allows the timing error to accumulate until a bit is lost or gained, corrupting the transmission.

Comment: That is a nice explanation for why always only the exact same 70 out of 650 bytes were received in my scenario. And I suppose sending back debugging info while sending data to the controller makes things worse.

Comment: @GrahamNye, hmm, okay. I did always think UARTs resynched on the leading edge of the start bit anyway, regardless of the gap, but I suppose they don't have to.

Comment: @ilkkachu A UART will start its character reception on the first 1 to 0 transition it sees after finishing the previous character reception sequence. If the clocks are correct that transition will be the leading edge of a start bit. If the clock has a modest error (insufficient to cause bit slip in a single character) but there is a sufficiently long inter-character gap the reception sequence will finish in the gap (which will be a 1 on the line, looking like extra stop bits) and the next 1 to 0 transition will be the leading edge of the start bit of the next character which will also be ...

Comment: @ilkkachu ... received correctly,  and so on. But if characters are being sent continuously, with no inter-character gap, the timing will slip until the receiving UART is looking for a start bit in the middle of the data part of a character. The first 1 to 0 transition it sees in data will be interpreted as a start bit and a corrupted character will be received. Typically a series of corrupted characters will be received until the UART can regain character sync.

Comment: @GrahamNye, yes, that's exactly how I imagined it would work. But, that would seem like a couple of extra one-bits should be enough to fix it, no? If the timing is off by several bits at the end of a character, it's likely to be off by a bit already in the middle of the character, so we don't receive even the first character correctly. But here, they said that _"if I reduce the sleep to below 0.05 seconds, transfer is unreliable"_, and at 38400 b/s, that amounts to almost 2000 extra bits. What I don't get is how 2000 extra bits would help, if 1000 (or 10) already don't.

Comment: (Also, if the sync goes off, I'd imagine they should be getting corrupted characters, as (without parity) pretty much anything should go as long as the stop bit gets detected correctly at the correct time after the edge that got detected as the start. I'd imagine there should be at least a couple of such within the 600-ish characters they said were not received. Well, assuming random-ish data anyway.)

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm only describing generic UART action. Actual performance will also depend on OP's code, which I'm not commenting on. I think we've had a more than reasonable amount of follow up comments so if you have further queries I suggest you  raise a new question (or experiment on your own ATMega) before we are banished to the land of chat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> an AVR ATmega MCU sitting on a breadboard, running at 8 MHz with the internal oscillator.

This is likely to be your problem. This Atmel [application note](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/OTH/ApplicationNotes/ApplicationNotes/Atmel-2555-Internal-RC-Oscillator-Calibration-for-tinyAVR-and-megaAVR-Devices_ApplicationNote_AVR053.pdf) ([source](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes?rv=1234ab57#)) suggests that an uncalibrated internal clock can have a tolerance of as much as ±10% (depending on the model) which is too loose for reliable serial communications.

You can calibrate the internal oscillator but temperature variations can still make it unsuitable for serial comms (see fig 1-2 of the app note).

You can verify if this is the problem by looking for framing errors from your ATmega USART.

You would be better off using an external crystal. This earlier [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545959/what-to-consider-when-choosing-a-crystal) might help.

Comment: It is pure magic. Just added a 16 MHz crystal and two caps, and now it races. Before, with all the throttling, writing a 17418 byte image took 990 seconds. Now it takes less than 5 @38.4k Baud. Slight improvement.

Comment: The clever question (thanks to [Claude Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem)!) is whether *lowering* the baud rate would eventually allow finishing the task *faster* ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl This is not a problem of data rate vs S/N and bandwidth as discussed by Shannon. It's a framing error because the clock rate is wrong. Instead of each bit being sampled precisely once an occasional bit is either sampled twice or missed out giving communication errors. Lowering the baud rate won't prevent this.

Comment: @GrahamNye Are you saying the 10% error affects all baud rates the same way? My guess was the lower the baud rate, the lower the relative error would be (and thus fewer errors should be observed).

Comment: @U.Windl Yes. All baud rates will have the same error. What's likely to happen is that the framing error shows up after the same number of bits so slowing the baud rate increases the time between framing errors.

Comment: @U.Windl If you calculate baud rates such as 1200 or 2400 based on 8 MHz clock, then if the 8 MHz clock is 10% too slow, also the 1200 and 2400 baud rates are 10% slow. The point about high baud rates is different, because with 8 MHz clock, it is impossible to get 115200 baud anyway.

Answer (score 6):

So you are using the internal oscillator.

This is most likely the issue.

You don't say which AVR you are using, but generally, internal oscillators on AVRs are not accurate enough for UART.

At least not without fine-tuning the oscillator frequency manually.

The oscillator frequency needs to be within 2% tolerance to work and preferably much less.

For a generic AVR like Mega328P, the factory calibration is done at 3V and 25°C and only to accuracy of within 10% tolerance.

So the expectation is that internal oscillator should not be used for UART, or at least not without user calibration. It simply might not work at all with factory calibration.

One way to figure out a suitable calibration value is to write a for loop going through all calibration register values and printing out what the value is. Smallest and largest values will not work correctly and don't print properly.
For the values that do work properly, pick a value from the middle of the range that works.

Comment: I'd of course accept your answer too, if it would be possible to accept more than one answer.